# Unable to receive value from switch statement inside loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm having this issue where I get no return value from the loop I created.

The idea is simple - I need to be updated from second to second how far my train reached. If reaching a number of seconds rolling, it means that it is on its way to a station, or exactly in a station. Here is my code, below.

Thanks, and hopefully I won't miss-post this.

```
function Train(speed, distance, elapsedTime, eTA, station, condition, type) {
  this.speed = speed;
  this.station = station;
  this.distance = distance;
  this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime;
  this.eTA = eTA;
  this.condition = condition;
  this.type = this.speed == 30 ? 'Regio' : this.speed == 70 ? 'Inter-Regio' : 'Broken'; 
}

var trainOne = new Train(30, '', '', '', '', '', '');
var elapsedTime = 
  function theLoop (elapsedTime) {
    setTimeout (function(){
    switch(elapsedTime){
      case elapsedTime == 0:
        Train().station = 'Station A';
        Train().eTA = 28 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
        break;

      case elapsedTime < 28:
        Train().station = 'Train left station A';
        Train().eTA = 28 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
        break;

      case elapsedTime == 28:
        Train().station = 'Station 2';
        Train().eTA = 28 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
        break;

      case elapsedTime > 28 && elapsedTime < 70:
        Train().station = 'Train left station 2';
        Train().eTA = 70 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
        break;

      case elapsedTime == 70:
        Train().station = 'Station 3';
        Train().eTA = 84 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
        break;

      default :
        Train().station = 'Station A';
        Train().eTA = 'No information available yet';
    }
    console.log(trainOne);
    if (++elapsedTime && elapsedTime < 12) {
      theLoop(elapsedTime);
    }
  }, 1000);
} (0);
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Also, is `switch` necessary here? How about `if-else` ?

Comment: Even tho that situation is solved, I can add another question. How do I pause the execution of a case for 5 seconds (for the case where the train reached the station). setTimeout doesn't seem to work for me..

Comment: @vivek_23 why would I go for if-else since I have the possiblity where the train is in station A (point is, why make the entire if-else-if-else run when I can save some time and memory using switch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try another one:

```js
function Train(speed, distance, elapsedTime, eTA, station, condition, type) {
  this.speed = speed;
  this.station = station;
  this.distance = distance;
  this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime;
  this.eTA = eTA;
  this.condition = condition;
  this.type = this.speed == 30 ? 'Regio' : this.speed == 70 ? 'Inter-Regio' : 'Broken';

  let timerID = null;

  this.run = function() {
    timerID = setInterval((self) => {
      self.elapsedTime++;
      self.distance += speed;
      console.log(`${self.elapsedTime} seconds, distance: ${self.distance}`);
    }, 1000, this);
  }

  this.stop = function() {
    console.log("Stop");
    clearInterval(timerID);
  }

  this.pause = function() {
    clearInterval(timerID);
  }

  this.station = function(name, duration) {
    console.log(`Station ${name}`);

    this.pause();

    setTimeout((self) => {
      console.log(`Live station ${name}`);
      self.run();
    }, duration, this, name);
  }
}

var trainOne = new Train(30, 0, '', 0, '', '', '');

trainOne.run();

setTimeout(() => {
  trainOne.station("A", 5000);
}, 5000);

setTimeout(() => {
  trainOne.station("B", 5000);
}, 15000);

setTimeout(() => {
  trainOne.stop();
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Nice one! I wish I could fully understand the code w/o any googlein' but I'll search for those statements. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function Train(speed, distance, elapsedTime, eTA, station, condition, type) {
  this.speed = speed;
  this.station = station;
  this.distance = distance;
  this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime;
  this.eTA = eTA;
  this.condition = condition;
  this.type = this.speed == 30 ? 'Regio' : this.speed == 70 ? 'Inter-Regio' : 'Broken';
}

var trainOne = new Train(30, 0, '', 0, '', '', '');

function theLoop(elapsedTime) {
  setTimeout(function() {

    trainOne.distance += trainOne.speed * elapsedTime;

    if (elapsedTime === 0) {
      trainOne.station = 'Station A';
      trainOne.eTA = 28 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
    } else if (elapsedTime < 28) {
      trainOne.station = 'Train left station A';
      trainOne.eTA = 28 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
    } else if (elapsedTime === 28) {
      trainOne.station = 'Station 2';
      trainOne.eTA = 28 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
    } else if (elapsedTime > 28 && elapsedTime < 70) {
      trainOne.station = 'Train left station 2';
      trainOne.eTA = 70 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
    } else if (elapsedTime === 70) {
      trainOne.station = 'Station 3';
      trainOne.eTA = 84 - elapsedTime + 'seconds left untill reaching the next station';
    }

    console.log(elapsedTime);
    console.log(trainOne.station);

    if (elapsedTime < 100) {
      theLoop(++elapsedTime);
    }

  }, 1000);
};

theLoop(0);
```

Hope, this help you.